# Response function replacing port as undefined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have a method which appends the object to the url. I am using ionic and java as my backend. Below is the method.

```
public buildUrl(urlDetails:Object, vals:Object):string {
        let baseUrl = urlDetails["url"];
        console.log(baseUrl)
        console.log(vals)
        //replace $(..) with the values from vals
        let keys = vals ? Object.keys(vals) : null
        if(keys && keys.length > 0) {
            return baseUrl.replace(/:(\w+)/g, (_,k) => vals[k]);
        } else {
            return baseUrl;
        }
```

For Example parameters passed to an object is as shown below,

urlDetails : http://192.168.0.109:8080/hiya/user/login

vals :{emailid:'test@test.com,password:'password'}

Here the **baseUrl.replace(/:(\w+)/g, (_,k) => vals[k])** functions removes the ":8080" from baseurl and resulting baseurl will be as shown below

http://192.168.0.109undefined/hiya/user/login

I guess something wrong with the **baseUrl.replace(/:(\w+)/g, (_,k) => vals[k])**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? That is, what is "append the object to the url" meant to mean?

Comment: Could you add to your question how you want the URL to like after `vals` was applied, please?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer), please *stick around* for a few minutes so you can answer queries such as the above.

Answer (score 2):

Your `replace` replaces whatever follows the `:` (in this case, `"8080"`, which your callback receives as `k`) with whatever is on the `vals` object for the property named with that string (`"8080"`). Your `vals` object doesn't have any property with the name `"8080"`, so `vals[k]` is `undefined`.

I'd say what to do instead, but it's not clear what you mean by "append the object to the URL" and why you're targeting the port for replacement.

If, for instance, you were trying to apply the object's properties to the URL as query string parameters, you wouldn't use `replace` on the port to do that. Since you seem to be targeting modern environments, I'd probably loop through the result of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (which is easily polyfilled if necessary) and append to the string, being certain to property encode the URI components with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript/reference/global_objects/encodeuricomponent):

```js
function buildUrl(urlDetails, vals) {
    let baseUrl = urlDetails["url"];
    let sep = "?";
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(vals)) {
        baseUrl += `${sep}${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
        sep = "&";
    }
    return baseUrl;
}
console.log(
    buildUrl(
        {url: "http://192.168.0.109:8080/hiya/user/login"},
        {emailid:'test@test.com',password:'password'}
    )
);
```

or with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
function buildUrl(urlDetails, vals) {
    let baseUrl = urlDetails.url;
    const entries = Object.entries(vals);
    if (entries.length) {
        baseUrl += "?" + entries.map(([key, value]) =>
            `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`
        ).join("&");
    }
    return baseUrl;
}
console.log(
    buildUrl(
        {url: "http://192.168.0.109:8080/hiya/user/login"},
        {emailid:'test@test.com',password:'password'}
    )
);
```